# SQL employees working for contractors

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have a database and i need to answer a question whether some employee works for multiple contractors. I believe that all this info is in one table.

- `contract` (contractor_no FK ,emp_no FK, job_no FK, is_active)

other tables that might be involved

- `cont_employee` (emp_no PK, emp_fname, emp_lname, birth_date)
- `contractor` (contractor_no PK, contractor_name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the employee and select only those having more than one record

```
select e.emp_no, e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname
from cont_employee e
join contract c on e.emp_no = c.emp_no
where c.is_active = 1
group by e.emp_no, e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname
having count(distinct c.contractor_no) > 1
```

Comment: And what if I wanted to add employees names so I would not get numbers only ?

Answer (score 0):

above query using group by on varchar column and also using distinct .
you can try row_number.
like this,

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select e.emp_no, e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname
,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY emp_no 
ORDER BY contractor_no) ROWNUM
from cont_employee e
join contract c on e.emp_no = c.emp_no
where c.is_active = 1
)T4
WHERE ROWNUM>1
```